# If condition in django templates not working

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have tried the if condition based on the value defined in the django template

```
{% if randomgen == 2 %}
<p style="float:right;text-align: center;padding:5px 5px;"><b>{% randomgen %}1</p>
{% else %}
<p style="float:right;text-align: center;padding:5px 5px;"><b>{% randomgen %} 2</p>
{% endif %}
```

the randomgen is defined to pick in random between 1 and 2 and the value is being displayed correctly in

tag but irrespective of the value it always going to else condition

```py
register = template.Library()

@register.tag(name="randomgen")
def randomgen(parser, token):
    items = []
    bits =  token.split_contents()
    for item in bits:
        items.append(item)
    return RandomgenNode(items[1:])

    def render(self, context):
        arg1 = 0
        arg2 = 10
        if "float" in self.items:
            result = random.randint(1,20)
        elif not self.items:
            result = random.randint(1,20)
        else:
            result = random.randint(1,2)
        return result
```

Comment: What is `{% randomgen %}` doing? Can you share the implementation of your `randomgen` function (or the view that generates it)?

Comment: first make sure the value in `randomgen` is an integer. I think its type is not integer, then because you

Comment: register = template.Library()

@register.tag(name="randomgen")
def randomgen(parser, token):
    items = []
    bits =  token.split_contents()
    for item in bits:
        items.append(item)
    return RandomgenNode(items[1:])


    
    def render(self, context):
        arg1 = 0
        arg2 = 10
        if "float" in self.items:
            result = random.randint(1,20)
        elif not self.items:
            result = random.randint(1,20)
        else:
            result = random.randint(1,2)
        return result

Comment: Hey Bibin, it'll be more helpful if you can edit your original question to add the code of `randomgen`, where you can use code formatting. It's extremely difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: Sure , Have done that .. But basically the issue is more to do with the html reference of the tag . Although the values generated are coming correctky only the if condition is not working correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML, set `randomgen` to another variable:

```
{% randomgen as rgen %}
```

Then use the newly set variable for your conditional:

```
{% if rgen == 2 %}
```

Honestly, I was surprised your code didn't work as your usage makes sense intuitively.  Knowing that it doesn't work though, my guess is the template is comparing a function with an integer which is always going to return False.  Good question!

Comment: Tried but same . No luck .. Still its always going to the else condition

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  Also, is there a reason you are using "@register.tag" instead of "@register.simple_tag"?

Comment: Django==2.2.5 and have tried simple_tag as well but dint work

Comment: Actually it worked . Checked again and it worked .. Thanks a lot Zenon

Comment: Awesome!  Did you keep your code as is and just change tag to simple_tag?

Comment: Yes , I changed them to simple tag